# Cannot correct load external js file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JS file for dynamic tooltips, if I use the codes with `script` tag in the html page it works. But when I use the `script src` tag to use it from a source, the script loads but when I try with the tooltips works, they don't work. This is the JS code

```
var tooltips = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip div');

window.onmousemove = function (e) {
    var x = (e.clientX + 20) + 'px',
        y = (e.clientY + 20) + 'px';
    for (var i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {
        tooltips[i].style.top = y;
        tooltips[i].style.left = x;
    }
};
```

Comment: make sure the external script is loaded/executed AFTER the dom finishes parsing, otherwise `.tooltip div` may not exist (yet).

Comment: your script tries to assign before the dom is completly loaded. look @Steve Pitis answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this script only when your HTML is rendered.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var tooltips = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip div');

    window.onmousemove = function (e) {
        var x = (e.clientX + 20) + 'px',
            y = (e.clientY + 20) + 'px';
        for (var i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {
            tooltips[i].style.top = y;
            tooltips[i].style.left = x;
        }
    };
}
```